# FormData.get and set not working in edge browser neither IE

Tags: jquery

I'm using `FormData` and it's working well in chrome and firefox but not in edge browser, the error says :

> the object doesn't accept property or method 'get'

the code is

```
 var form = new FormData($("#request-form")[0]);
 console.log(form.get("id_planta"))
```

Does anybody know a way to get it working?

Comment: It's not supported in Edge https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData and https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/catalog/?page=1&q=formdata. You can get the values directly from the form with jQuery or plain JavaScript.

Comment: the bad thing is that i'm about the 80 or 85 % of the application and just realized that was not working in edge. have to change a lot of code because of this issue

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
//var form = new FormData($("#request-form")[0]);
var planta = $("#request-form").find("input[name=id_planta]");
console.log(planta.val());
```

Comment: you should add some explanations to your answer.